# Is there any way to replace double quotes in entire object dynamically based on conditions

Tags: javascript, json

I am having one object like below and now I need to remove the double quotes if the any of the value is either Number or null. Other than these three cases, double quotes should be present.

All these values are fetching from textbox, If I provide value as 1234, its getting added as "1234".

so, here itself I am facing this issue. How to avoid this? Please advise

```
{
   "fruits":[{
     "name":"apple",
     "count":"4",
     "filter":{
        "unique":[{
              "attribute":"isFruit",
              "identifier":"9876"
           }],
        "match_attributes":{
           "location":"NewZeland",
           "subname":"null"
        },
        "match_expressions":[{
          "attribute":"value1",
          "operator":"In",
          "values":["test_value","4567","value7"]
       },
       {
          "attribute_name":"isvegetable",
          "operator":"In",
          "values":["15678"]
       }]
     }
  }]
}
```

My expected output should be like below,

```
{
   "fruits":[{
     "name":"apple",
     "count":4,
     "filter":{
        "unique":[{
              "attribute":"isFruit",
              "identifier": 9876
           }],
        "match_attributes":{
           "location":"NewZeland",
           "subname":null
        },
        "match_expressions":[{
          "attribute":"value1",
          "operator":"In",
          "values":["test_value",4567,"value7"]
       },
       {
          "attribute_name":"isvegetable",
          "operator":"In",
          "values":[15678]
       }]
     }
  }]
}
```

I tried to remove for single value using

```
string.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
```

But is there any way to replace it for an entire object. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about fixing the source of that "invalid" JSON?

Comment: Why do you want to add the boolean value as text in textbox?? Why don't you handle it with radio buttons or checkbox??

Comment: That will be dynamic tetxbox, where user can enter any string or number or boolean like 1234, false, value1, value2 etc...

Comment: textbox only handle strings, so if you do want to distinguish string from numbers and boolean, you will have to cast the input value to either bool or string. You will need a way to know before casting the type to cast to (int or bool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own parser to handle the special cases words you want to convert. In this case 'true', 'false' and 'null'

As for the numbers you can check if it's a number or not using `isNaN` then format it.

```js
const input = {
   "fruits":[{
     "name":"apple",
     "count":"4",
     "filter":{
        "unique":[{
              "attribute":"isFruit",
              "identifier":"true"
           }],
        "match_attributes":{
           "location":"NewZeland",
           "subname":"null"
        },
        "match_expressions":[{
          "attribute":"value1",
          "operator":"In",
          "values":["test_value","4567","value7"]
       },
       {
          "attribute_name":"isvegetable",
          "operator":"In",
          "values":["false"]
       }]
     }
  }]
};

const dictionary = ["null", "true", "false"]

const parser = word => {
  wordWithoutQuotes = word.substring(1, word.length -1)
  if (dictionary.includes(wordWithoutQuotes) || !isNaN(wordWithoutQuotes)) return JSON.parse(word)
  
  return word
  
}
const output = JSON.stringify(input).replace(/".*?"/g, parser);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: @Melchia, This is working like charm. But how you are converting numbers isNaN()?. Thank you so much.